# PostgreSQL: ERROR: query returned 2 columns

Tags: postgresql, stored-functions

My function is like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_o_record_desc()
     RETURNS text
     LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $$

DECLARE
o_record TEXT DEFAULT '';
rec_o_record RECORD;
cur_o_record CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM o_record_fact;
v_spent_desc varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL;
    
BEGIN
-- Open the cursor
OPEN cur_o_record;
LOOP
-- Fetch row into the person
    FETCH cur_o_record INTO rec_o_record;
-- Exit when no more row to fetch
    EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
    
    EXECUTE 'SELECT string_agg(value_label, ', ') as vlabel FROM spent_table WHERE code ~* $1'
    INTO v_spent_desc
    USING regexp_replace(TRIM(rec_o_record.spent_column), '(.)(?!$)','\1|','g');
END LOOP;
-- Close the cursor
CLOSE cur_o_record;
RETURN o_record;
END;
$$;

select insert_o_record_desc();
```

Then I got an error with this message

> ERROR:  query returned 2 columns
> CONTEXT:  query: 'SELECT string_agg(value_label1, ', ') as vlabel FROM spent_table WHERE code ~* $1'
> PL/pgSQL function insert_o_record_desc() line 123 at EXECUTE
> SQL state: 42601

but when i just run this query

```
SELECT string_agg(value_label, ', ') as vlabel FROM spent_table WHERE code ~* 'A|B|C|E';
```

I got result with one column. why is that?

Comment: Why a cursor? And to be honest, just a plain SQL function with a single query using a JOIN to match both tables, would be good enough for this. Not even a need for a function, you can do it in a view.

Comment: it is not the whole function, theres updating event happening in the whole function but I just put here the one that is making an error.

Comment: Even then, cursors are hardly used in PostgreSQL plpgsql because plpgsql does this automatically under the hood: `(However, PL/pgSQL users do not normally need to worry about that, since FOR loops automatically use a cursor internally to avoid memory problems.)`

Answer (score 0):

lol, stupid escape! **'',''**

```
    EXECUTE 'SELECT string_agg(value_label,'','') as vlabel FROM spent_table WHERE code ~* $1'
```